# Keeping points in order about a circle in NetworkX graph visualization?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I am new to NetworkX and am trying to use it for analysis of a personal project.
I have a function that generates edges, for example,
`[(0, 6), (6, 12), (12, 2), (2, 8), (8, 14), (14, 4), (4, 10), (10, 0)]`
I would like this to be pushed out onto a circle, which I have accomplished with the  `pos=nx.spiral_layout(g)` parameter. However, when I do this, I get the following: [image]

While I would like the points to be on a circle, I would like them to be in order: (0, 1, 2 ... ) in order to have their edges drawn in the middle. I have seen that I can manually input the locations of the points I want, but I am sure there is a better way to do that.
The code I am currently using to generate the graph and print it is this:

```
g = nx.Graph(edge_generator(5,4))
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True, pos=nx.spiral_layout(g))
```

Seen above is what actually happened, whereas I would like something that looks more like a star.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own layout function like this
Something like this:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def circle_layout(g, r=10):
    layout = {}
    n = max(g.nodes.items())[0] + 1
    step = 2 * np.pi / n
    for node in g.nodes.items():
        layout[node[0]] = [r * np.sin(node[0]*step), r * np.cos(node[0]*step)]
    return layout

edgelist = [(0, 6), (6, 12), (12, 2), (2, 8), (8, 14), (14, 4), (4, 10), (10, 0)]
g = nx.from_edgelist(edgelist)
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True, pos=circle_layout(g))
```

produces:

[image]